# How to set up a Scala actor to exclusively use a separate thread to run?

Tags: multithreading, scala, actor

As far as I understand, Scala manages a thread pool to run actors, sharing threads among them. Can I set up a particular actor to run in a separate thread exclusively, never sharing it with another actor?

Comment: @pablo-fernandez to use `java.lang.Thread.sleep(long millis)` safely, without freezing any other actors which could share the same thread. The actual task is to create a timer actor sleeping between sending tick messages.

Comment: I'd use the executor framework if you need a finer control of the number of threads being involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Scala (not Akka) actors.  In that case if you use the `receive` or `receiveWithin` style of message handling then each actor will get its own thread.   Using the `react` style of message handling shares a thread pool among actors.

When I say the `receive` "style", I mean in a loop, for example:

```
val timerActor = actor { 
  while (true) {
    receiveWithin(60 * 1000) {
       case Stop => self.exit()
       case TIMEOUT =>
          destination ! Tick
    }
  }
}
```

In this case `timerActor` does not share its thread with any other actor.   `receiveWithin` will block until either the actor receives a Stop message or 60 seconds passes.   If 60 seconds passes then the TIMEOUT case is executed.

If you want to learn the gritty details about Scala actors, check out the paper [Actors That Unify Threads and Events](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~phaller/doc/haller07actorsunify.pdf).

Akka also supports thread-based actors in addition to event-based actors.